# (1/1) NotWritableException Can't write image data to path

Tags: laravel, image

I'm facing a rather interesting problem.On my local host everything seems to be working just fine but after hosting my project on the live server i'm getting this error

(1/1) NotWritableException
Can't write image data to path (/home/floatin2/public_html/public/avatar/band11.png)

This is my code:

```
     $imageData=$request->get('image-data');
     $imageData2=$request->get('second-image-data');
     $imageData3=$request->get('third-image-data');

     $info=base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '',$imageData));
     $info2=base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '',$imageData2));
     $info3=base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '',$imageData3));

     $img1=Image::make($info)->save(public_path('/avatar/band1'. auth()->user()->id .'.png'));
     $img2=Image::make($info2)->save(public_path('/avatar/band2'. auth()->user()->id .'.png'));
     $img3=Image::make($info3)->save(public_path('/avatar/band3'. auth()->user()->id .'.png'));

     $user=Auth::user();
     $user->avatarband1='band1'. auth()->user()->id .'.png';
     $user->avatarband2='band2'. auth()->user()->id .'.png';
     $user->avatarband3='band3'. auth()->user()->id .'.png';
     $user->save();
```

Please tell me how to fix this

Comment: Well the clue is in the error. The user executing the script cannot write to the file location.

Comment: Oh my god,thank you so much.After reading your message it just struck me.I moved all the files from the public folder to the root level and deleted the public folder.I works now.Cheers